# Get Selected value from Spinner inside ListView Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView of Spinners I'm trying to get the selected values out of. Some of the Spinners have the first selection automatically selected if there is only 1 item in the list, so I feel

> setOnItemSelectedListener

won't necessarily work? Either way, I'm unsure how to code this scenario. Even if I had the listener coded correctly, How do I use it in my class to work with the adapter?

CustomAdapter

```
public class CustomPLNViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> partLotNumbersArrayList;
private static ArrayList<String> partNames;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

private Context myContext;

public CustomPLNViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> results, ArrayList<String> parts){
    partLotNumbersArrayList = results;
    partNames = parts;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    myContext = context;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return partLotNumbersArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return partLotNumbersArrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_assembly_parts, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.partName);
        holder.spinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.LotNumbers);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtName.setText(partNames.get(position));        

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(myContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, partLotNumbersArrayList.get(position));          
    adp1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    //set the adapter to the spinnner
    holder.spinner.setAdapter(adp1);

    //if there is only one other part besides "" then set that as default part
    if(partLotNumbersArrayList.get(position).size() == 2){
        holder.spinner.setSelection(1);
    }   

    return convertView;
}



static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    Spinner spinner;
}
}
```

Where I am calling the code. Obviously I get an error here because an ArrayList cannot be cast to Spinner, but I'm unsure how to get the View of the Adapter and then the subsequent spinner?

```
// save button click event
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Log.d("lv count", Integer.toString(lv.getCount()));

            //iterate through listview, 
            for(int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++){
                Spinner temp = (Spinner) lv.getItemAtPosition(i);                   
                Log.d("lv isItemCheck", temp.getSelectedItem().toString());

            }   
            //check to make sure all items have been selected
            if(!checkAllParts()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Select All List Items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All items have been selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            //go back to previous intent, return 100 that saving succeeded 

            //close intent
        }
    });
```

Comment: `(Spinner) lv.getItemAtPosition` => `((Spinner) lv).getSelectedItem` directly, no?

Comment: error: cannot convert from Object to Spinner. also your code doesn't look valid?

Comment: I just tried `Spinner temp = ((Spinner) lv.getSelectedItem());` which is valid, but I'm not sure how to use the Spinner object after that.

Comment: you need to put a spinner listener on each spinner.

Comment: (because you can't reach them by iterating on the list, as possibly some have not been created yet, because they are not visible)

Comment: how do i access the listener outside of the adapter? can you post an example?

Comment: you can't, since the adapter creates the spinner, and you can't control when the adapter is called to create the views.

Comment: So then I'm back to my original problem. I have no idea how to get the values out of the spinners to either check if something is selected or what that selection is. if I create a listener, what do I put in the `onItemSelected` area to be able to be usable in my main?

Comment: the problem is that you cannot know that the spinner has even been created. You have to store the values for the spinner somewhere else, have a default value there, and change that value when the user changes the selection of the spinner

Comment: That seems rather short sighted on Android's part but your answer makes sense. Now i just have to figure out where to store the values. Any hints on doing that?

Comment: I wouldn't say short-sighted, no. When you start using slightly more complicated data in your views, you are encouraged to separate the model and the view, and have a class that holds your data.